# Slow Flash Animation on some mobile phones

Tags: performance, mobile, flashlite

I have this flash animation (flash lite 1.1) and the problem is that on my phone it's quite slow.

It looks like as it was 5-6 FPS....

Could anyone tell me why and how to make it faster?

Thank you in advance.

Here are the swf and fla files:
[Download](http://www.speedyshare.com/342522284.html)

***Edit:*** tested on SonyEricsson K550, W610, W300 and W880

Comment: This might be more appropriate to ask on superuser?

Comment: iPhone doesn't have Flash. Retagged!

Comment: It's development related - it should be here.

Comment: Why the flashlite tag has been removed?

Comment: @rpetrich Who mentioned iPhone?

Comment: @willc2: skaffman had edited the tags to include the iphone tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance problems in Flash Lite are usually best addressed by simplifying the rendering - making animations shorter, smaller, and using less complicated contents. Some specific ideas that often increase performance are:

- Complicated vectors, non-device text, and gradients are all costly to render. Replace them with bitmaps (if you can do so without exceeding memory constraints).
- Limit the use of transparency, and limit the number of layers involved.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your files, you could do the following:

1. You're using particle effects, this is cpu-intensive. Reducing the number of particles could impact the playback speed.
2. Each particle has an alpha fade effect. Reducing the duration of the alpha fade, or removing it completely will help.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded the SWF and ran it on my Nokia 6500s, it worked pretty smooth, definitely not 5-6 FPS.

I don't think you'll be able to make it ran smoother on a slow phone (that's might be the problem), **while keeping the current graphic effects**.